# Error while reading data from USB DRIVE .MDF .LDF

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, networking

I have one USB Pen drive.
I create one SQL database to SQL server and set Restore ".MDF .LDF" path to My USB Pen drive. so that all data are saved in my USB Drive.

Now my question is that while i re-connect my USB Pendrive to Computer and open Sql server and fire select table query it dont show me my data.

Help..

[image]

Comment: Take a peek at https://serverfault.com/questions/48958/sql-server-database-on-an-external-hard-disk-drive

Comment: check above screenshot while select query file or edit data

Comment: Don't store a database on removable media... Period.

Comment: @Larnu yah thats right but my  client requirement is that store data into USB. Please help me

Comment: Doesn't matter; it won't work. If your client said that their requirement was for you to make a lead balloon float like a normal helium balloon, you wouldn't simply accept it. The same is true here. More often than not Clients don't understand the limitations or possibilities of a product, and it's your job to tell them when they're asking for impossible goals, underestimating the capabilities or (for lack of better words) begin stupid. The requirement for having a SQL Server database being hosted on a Removable Storage Device definitely falls under one of those criteria. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Larnu but what actually do for that if i really want to do that

Comment: My answer hasn't changed. You don't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172068/discussion-between-navnit-and-larnu).

Comment: Consider that you either misunderstood the client's requirements or that you messed up the implementation. You don't store SQL databases on removable media, just as @Larnu says. This requirement is just asking for data corruption, which I'm sure you nor the client want. Explain more about this scenario. Is it a Windows application that you install on the client's machine? You do realise that you'll have to install SQL Server on each client PC? Instead look into synchronization or backup, so copy the data to USB after each write to fixed disk or at an interval. You'll get sync issues then tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible.
You can work with your database again while re-connect your USB.
But you have to do one thing every time after you re-connect your USB.

1. Stop your SQL Service and Start Again.
2. Check now. Your project work fine.

Thanks.